# My second IF statement in this password checker isn't working and I'm unsure why

Tags: python

Ok, below is my code and I'm just puzzled as to why it can't validate if the password is all letter or numbers. The else statement works fine. Thank you for any help, I really appreciate it!

```
import datetime

MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 6
MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 10
password = input("Please create a password: ")
password_length = len(password)
PASSWORD_LOG_FILE = open('password_log.txt', "w")

while password_length < MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH or password_length > MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH:
    if password_length < MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH:
        current_date_and_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        error = (f"{current_date_and_time}, password < 6")
        PASSWORD_LOG_FILE.write(error)
        PASSWORD_LOG_FILE.write("\n")
    elif password_length > MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH:
        current_date_and_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        error = (f"{current_date_and_time}, password > 10")
        PASSWORD_LOG_FILE.write(error)
        PASSWORD_LOG_FILE.write("\n")
    print(f"Your password is {password_length} characters long, but it should be between 6-10.")
    password = input("Please create a valid password: ")
    password_length = len(password)

PASSWORD_LOG_FILE.close()

 if password.isdigit():
    message = "Password weak - contains only numbers."
 elif password.isalpha():
    message = "Password weak - contains only letters."
 else:
    message = "Password strong"

    print(f"Your password is {password_length} characters long. {message}")

    PASSWORD_LOG_FILE = open('password_log.txt', 'r')
    for line in PASSWORD_LOG_FILE:
        print(line, end='')
    PASSWORD_LOG_FILE.close()
```

Comment: what password are you introducing and what is the result of the conditional that you say doesn't work?

Comment: it looks like the indentation is off, I would assume that the line where you print message should be outside of the else block

Comment: The last block of code is all in the `else:`, so `message` isn't printed for the weak  cases.

Comment: Thank you all so much for the feedback! It was defintely an "omg wow how could i miss it" moment haha

Comment: @Script_Kiddy74 If you found any answer helpful then you can click on the tick mark to accept it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your indentation is wrong, the print statement falls into `else:` so it only print when password is strong.

You should move the print statement

```
if password.isdigit():
    message = "Password weak - contains only numbers."
elif password.isalpha():
    message = "Password weak - contains only letters."
else:
    message = "Password strong"
print(f"Your password is {password_length} characters long. {message}")
```

Answer (score 0):

The last block of code was in the `else:`, so the message wasn't printed for the `isdigit()` or `isalpha()` cases. Also, I can see that you are having some irregular indentation in your code. Kindly fix that.

```
import datetime

MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 6
MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 10
password = input("Please create a password: ")
password_length = len(password)
PASSWORD_LOG_FILE = open('password_log.txt', "w")

while password_length < MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH or password_length > MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH:
    if password_length < MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH:
        current_date_and_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        error = (f"{current_date_and_time}, password < 6")
        PASSWORD_LOG_FILE.write(error)
        PASSWORD_LOG_FILE.write("\n")
    elif password_length > MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH:
        current_date_and_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        error = (f"{current_date_and_time}, password > 10")
        PASSWORD_LOG_FILE.write(error)
        PASSWORD_LOG_FILE.write("\n")
    print(f"Your password is {password_length} characters long, but it should be between 6-10.")
    password = input("Please create a valid password: ")
    password_length = len(password)

PASSWORD_LOG_FILE.close()

if password.isdigit():
 message = "Password weak - contains only numbers."
elif password.isalpha():
 message = "Password weak - contains only letters."
else:
 message = "Password strong"

print(f"Your password is {password_length} characters long. {message}")

PASSWORD_LOG_FILE = open('password_log.txt', 'r')
for line in PASSWORD_LOG_FILE:
   print(line, end='')
PASSWORD_LOG_FILE.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

like people mentiond in the comments, the print statement you are expecting is inside the else block, change it into this:

```
if password.isdigit():
 message = "Password weak - contains only numbers."
elif password.isalpha():
 message = "Password weak - contains only letters."
else:
 message = "Password strong"
print(f"Your password is {password_length} characters long. {message}")
```